# What is ENU frame in IMU?

Tags: imu, robot-localization, ros-noetic

I'm trying to fuse gps and imu data through the robot_localization package. According to the package description, the robot_localization package assumes an ENU frame for IMU data, which I don't understand very well. If IMU data assumes an ENU frame, does it get an absolute orientation value where yaw value becomes 0 when looking east? Also, I'm not sure which sensor to buy for this. Currently I have a 6-axis IMU that publishes only the acceleration and angular velocity values, do I need to buy a new IMU?

Comment: What is your IMU (make/model)? Please [edit] and update your question

Comment: Does this help: [IMU sensor is in which frame, ENU or NED frame??](https://answers.ros.org/question/391811/imu-sensor-is-in-which-frame-enu-or-ned-frame/). Here are [some other questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Arobotics.stackexchange.com+%22IMU+sensor+is+in+which+frame%2C+ENU+or+NED+frame%3F%3F%22) that *might* help.